# Symfony2: How to change the base-url/hostname generated by Assetic's asset() function to localhost?

Tags: image, symfony, assets, assetic

I downloaded a project from my production server.

Now the image rendered with ...

```
<img src="{{ asset('uploaded_images/') }}{{ variable.getPath() }}">
```

... returns a `404` error because the generated URL still contains the production server's domain.

How can I change the generated URL's hostname to `localhost`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to have all `asset('..')` paths use `localhost` as hostname ...

... adapt the [`framework.templating.assets_base_url`](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets-base-urls) setting.

---

**config.yml**

```
framework:
    templating: 
        assets_base_url: 
            http: 'http://localhost'
            ssl:  'https://localhost'
```